# Python with selenium: unable to locate element xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/popout/gaules/chat?popout=')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button').click()

name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('*//p[@class="sc-AxirZ bmRDsM"]')

driver.close()
print(name.text)
```

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"*//p[@class="sc-AxirZ bmRDsM"]"}

why not i receive the name "Gaules" as response?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you already closed your driver session.
It should work:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('*//p[@class="sc-AxirZ bmRDsM"]').text
```